# schema not found in 'normalizr'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga, normalizr

I have a React + Redux + Saga + TypeScript application. I'm trying to add normalizr to it.
Version from package.json `"normalizr": "^3.6.1",`

When I try to import `schema`

`import { normalize, schema } from "normalizr";`

I get

`schema not found in 'normalizr'`

What I tried to do:

- Add `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]` to tsconfig file ([original post](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/271))

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find an answer? Ran into the same problem today.